# setHorizontallyScrolling causes text to restart in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have added marquee effect in my TextView and appending text to this TextView at run time. After appending I call setHorizontallyScrolling to avoid text overwriting. But this call causes the text to restart again. Is it possible to stop this restart and continue scrolling? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a solution that lets you change the value of the `horizontallyScrolling` attribute without resetting the marquee timer. You may have to set that value in your layout XML to true before you even start appending new text. If you do that then it SHOULDN'T reset when you just append text and should just continue scrolling.

Comment: You are right Femi. But at this time the text gets overwritten :( Same issue is mentioned in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631262/marquee-text-gets-overwritten